# EXC_BAD_ACCESS : ESRI ARCGis Maps

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, arcgis, esri

Using ESRI ARCGis Maps into app, Crashlytics reported some crashes with following stack trace, but not able to reproduce it.

Any direction how to debug this crash.

```
#0
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000
 Raw Text
0
libsystem_platform.dylib    
_platform_memmove + 176
3
GLEngine    
glDrawElements_ACC_ES2Exec
4   MyCity  
Esri_runtimecore::Map_renderer::Sequence_pick_visitor::draw_() + 396
5   MyCity  
Esri_runtimecore::Map_renderer::Graphic_buffer::visit_sequences_(std::__1::shared_ptr<Esri_runtimecore::HAL::Device> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<Esri_runtimecore::Map_renderer::Sequence_visitor> const&, Esri_runtimecore::Map_renderer::Graphic_buffer::Allow_throttling, bool) + 972
6   MyCity  
Esri_runtimecore::Map_renderer::Graphics_layer::gpu_hit_test_(std::__1::shared_ptr<Esri_runtimecore::HAL::Device> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<Esri_runtimecore::Map_renderer::Display_properties> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<Esri_runtimecore::Map_renderer::Hit_testable::Hit_test_request_details> const&) + 1004
7   MyCity  
Esri_runtimecore::Map_renderer::Graphics_layer::hit_test(std::__1::shared_ptr<Esri_runtimecore::Geometry::Multi_path> const&, unsigned long) + 460
8   MyCity  
-[AGSMapViewBase hitTestPoint:mapPoint:] + 232
9   MyCity  
-[AGSMapView singleTap] + 336
10
UIKit   
_UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 164
21
UIKit   
UIApplicationMain + 204
22  MyCity  
AppDelegate.swift line 16
main
23  libdispatch.dylib   
(Missing)
```

Tried with NSZombieEnabled, but still not found anything.